# UnicodeDecodeError for writing file

Tags: python, networkx, gml

I know that this is a very common error, but it's the first time I've encountered it when trying to write a file.

I'm using `networkx` to work with graphs for network analysis, and when I try to write into any format:

```
nx.write_gml(G, "Graph.gml")
nx.write_pajek(G, "Graph.net")
nx.write_gexf(G, "graph.gexf")
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in write_pajek
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 263, in _open_file
    result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/pajek.py", line 100, in write_pajek
    path.write(line.encode(encoding))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I haven't found documentation on this, so quite confused.

Answer (score 2):

Wondering if you can make use of **codec** module to solve it or not. Just create a file object by **codec** as following before feeding to networkx.

ex,

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("graph.gml", "w", "utf-8")
```

Comment: @inselberg It depends on the encoding of your input file. `utf-8` here is just an example.