# Python write to json file gives UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, json, csv, utf-8

I have a list of dictionaries `final` and when I try to export it to json, I get the following error. In creating the final, I have used manipulation of some csv files that contain non-ascii characters. All csv files are UTF-8 type csv.

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
jsonfilename = os.path.join(dirname, 'Final_Results.json')
with open(jsonfilename, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(final, fp)
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop", line 138, in <module>  
    json.dump(final, fp)  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 189, in dump  
    for chunk in iterable:  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode  
    for chunk in _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level):  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 332, in _iterencode_list  
    for chunk in chunks:  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 390, in _iterencode_dict  
    yield _encoder(value)  
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: 
invalid continuation byte
```

A line from the csv file
`Walkers Meaty Variety Crisps 14x25g            Only Â£2.00: Save Â£1.00,Food Cupboard  Crisps, Snacks & Nuts,8,Walkers`

The code has

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

at the top.

I have also tried
 1. using codecs as some other posts have suggested.
[UnicodeDecodeError for WRITING File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097217/unicodedecodeerror-for-writing-file)
 2. Tried adding `encoding = 'utf-8'` to the json.dump line to no use.

What is the best way to go forward with this?
Using python 2.7

The following is the entire code
http://dpaste.com/1920N7Q

Here are snippets of the csv files
http://dpaste.com/1920N7Q

Comment: The error is not raise when writing but when encoding the data. Please show us some example data.

Comment: @thatrockbottomprogrammer Already mentioned it in the post, I've tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: @KlausD.Please check edits.

Comment: As it's a Unicode**De**codeError, it is obviously raised when **de**coding something (not **en**coding, @KlausD.). I think that you probably have some byte strings in `final`. The cleanest way to fix it would be using `io.open(filename, encoding='utf8')` for all input TSV files. But unfortunately, the `csv` library in Python 2.x can't handle unicode input, so that doesn't work. Can you upgrade to Python 3? It'll make encoding stuff *much* less confusing.

Comment: The origal data seems to have an encoding problem already. Or should the `Â` actually be there?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, that's definitely an encoding problem: it looks like the wrong codec was used for decoding (Latin-1 interpretation of UTF-8 bytes).

Comment: @inquisitiveProgrammer, you should provide more details about how you get the csv input data into the nested structure you describe. The line you posted contains mojibake, which is an encoding problem that ruins your data without raising exceptions. But the exception that *is* raised shows that something is decoded as UTF-8, even though it's the wrong codec. It could be a case of double-decoding – show your code.

Comment: @lenz please check edits. Have added the entire code and csv files.

Comment: @KlausD.please check edits. Have added the entire code and csv files.

Comment: @lenz Anything that can be modified to make it work. I've been trying for quite sometime but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I'm working in the wrong direction.

Comment: Does the answer linked to by the duplicate-markers help you? (I doubt it, because it involves using `codecs.open`, which is incompatible with the `csv` module in Python 2.) If not, you should try to get rid of the duplicate mark, so I can post an answer.

Comment: @lenz It does not. I have mentioned that in the question itself.

Comment: @lenz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851583/python-write-to-json-file-gives-unicodedecodeerror-worked-with-codecs-leads-to